# Count group by enum including possible enum values that have 0 count

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a table of items. One of the fields is a category (represented by an enum). Some categories have zero items.

So I did this:

```
select category, count(*) as total from items group by category;
+------------+-------+
| category   | total |
+------------+-------+
| one        |  6675 |
+------------+-------+
```

I want to generate a table like this (where two is the other possible enum value):

```
+------------+-------+
| category   | total |
+------------+-------+
| one        |  6675 |
+------------+-------+
| two        |  0    |
+------------+-------+
```

How do I do this with an mysql SQL query?

Comment: Are you categories listed in another table?

Comment: @abney317 that would be nice, right? Thinking I might be best to make that table

Comment: I agree with @abney317 - that way it's a simple grouping on a left joined table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some fun with MySQL 8.0 and [JSON_TABLE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html):

```
select c.category, count(i.category) as total
from information_schema.COLUMNS s
join json_table(
  replace(replace(replace(trim('enum' from s.COLUMN_TYPE),'(','['),')',']'),'''','"'),
  '$[*]' columns (category varchar(50) path '$')
) c
left join items i on i.category = c.category
where s.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'test' -- replace with your db/schema name
  and s.TABLE_NAME   = 'items'
  and s.COLUMN_NAME  = 'category'
group by c.category
```

It converts the ENUM type definition from `information_schema` to a JSON array, which is then converted by `JSON_TABLE()` to a table, which you then can use for a LEFT JOIN.

See demo on [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tejFf4ZZGj9E7HvUc78rtf/0)

Note: The categories should not contain any characters from `()[]'"`.

But seriously – Just create the `categories` table. There are more reasons to do that. For example you might want to render a drop-down menu with all possible categories. That would be simple with

```
select category from categories
```

Comment: I agree that using JSON_TABLE is more complicated than creating the categories table. What I wanted was confirmation that there was no simple way to do it without creating another table. If the enum needs to be updated it would make sense for there to be a single source of truth for the list of possible values, but it seems like that's not how SQL feels about it. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @voutasaurus Of course you should also use a foreign key in the `items` table, so you wouldn't be able to set the category to anything that is not in the `categories` table. Then you have your "single source of truth". It's even more strict than ENUM, since ENUM (AFAIK) always permits empty strings.

Answer (score 5):

Enum datatype is *generally* preferred for those cases where possible options (values) are not too many (prefer <= 10), and you are not going to add new options in future (atleast not very frequently). So, a good use-case for Enum is gender: `(m, f, n)`. In your case, it would be *generally better* to have a Master table of all possible Categories, instead of using Enum for them. Then it is easier to do a `LEFT JOIN` from the Master table.

However, as asked by you:

> A solution uses the enum type to generate the table, and includes 0
>   entries

**Works for all MySQL/MariaDB versions**:

We will need to get the list of all possible Enum values from [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/columns-table.html):

```
SELECT
   SUBSTRING(COLUMN_TYPE, 6, CHAR_LENGTH(COLUMN_TYPE) - 6) AS enum_values
FROM
    information_schema.COLUMNS
WHERE
    TABLE_NAME = 'items'        -- your table name
AND
    COLUMN_NAME = 'category'    -- name of the column
AND 
    TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_db'    -- name of the database (schema)
```

But then, this query will give you all the enum values in comma-separated string, like below:

`'one','two','three','four'`

Now, we will need to convert this string into **multiple** rows. To achieve that, we can use a Sequence (Number series) table. You can define a permanent table in your database storing integers ranging from 1 to 100 (you *may* find this table helpful in many other cases as well) (OR, another approach is to use a [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html) - check this to get an idea: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58052199/2469308).

```
CREATE TABLE seq (n tinyint(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(n));
INSERT INTO seq (n) VALUES (1), (2), ...... , (99), (100);
```

Now, we will do a JOIN between "enum values string" and `seq` table, based on the position of comma, to extract enum values into different rows. Note that instead of just using `,` (comma) to extract enum values, we would use `','` (to avoid cases when there might be a comma inside the value string). String operations utilizing [`Substring_Index()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index), [`Trim()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim), [`Char_Length()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length) etc functions can be used to extract enum values. You can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58032575/2469308) to get a general idea about this technique:

**Schema ([View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xe1Qcm4FEo4QeRnBx8v5z8/0))**

```
CREATE TABLE items 
(id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
 category ENUM('one','two','three','four'), 
 item_id INT UNSIGNED) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO items (category, item_id) 
VALUES ('one', 1), 
       ('two', 2), 
       ('one', 2), 
       ('one', 3);

CREATE TABLE seq (n tinyint(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
                  PRIMARY KEY(n));
INSERT INTO seq (n) VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT Trim(BOTH '\'' FROM Substring_index(Substring_index(e.enum_values,
                                           '\',\'',
                                                  seq.n),
                                  '\',\'', -1)) AS cat
FROM   (SELECT Substring(column_type, 6, Char_length(column_type) - 6) AS
               enum_values
        FROM   information_schema.columns
        WHERE  table_name = 'items'
               AND column_name = 'category'
               AND table_schema = 'test') AS e
       JOIN seq
         ON ( Char_length(e.enum_values) - Char_length(REPLACE(e.enum_values,
                                                       '\',\'',
                                                       ''))
            ) / 3 >= seq.n - 1

| cat   |
| ----- |
| one   |
| two   |
| three |
| four  |
```

---

Now, the hard part is done. All we need to do is do a `LEFT JOIN` from this subquery (having all category enum values) to your `items` table, to get Count per category.

The final query follows ([View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xe1Qcm4FEo4QeRnBx8v5z8/2)):

```
SELECT all_cat.cat                   AS category,
       Count(i.item_id) AS total
FROM   (SELECT Trim(BOTH '\'' FROM Substring_index(
                                   Substring_index(e.enum_values,
                                          '\',\'',
                                                  seq.n),
                                                  '\',\'', -1)) AS cat
        FROM   (SELECT Substring(column_type, 6, Char_length(column_type) - 6)
                       AS
                       enum_values
                FROM   information_schema.columns
                WHERE  table_name = 'items'
                       AND column_name = 'category'
                       AND table_schema = 'test') AS e
               JOIN seq
                 ON ( Char_length(e.enum_values) - Char_length(
                                                   REPLACE(e.enum_values,
                                                   '\',\'',
                                                   ''))
                    ) / 3 >= seq.n - 1) AS all_cat
       LEFT JOIN items AS i
              ON i.category = all_cat.cat
GROUP  BY all_cat.cat
ORDER  BY total DESC;
```

**Result**

```
| category | total |
| -------- | ----- |
| one      | 3     |
| two      | 1     |
| three    | 0     |
| four     | 0     |
```

Comment: You don't need `COALESCE()` for `COUNT()`. AFAIK `COUNT()` does never return `NULL`. At least not in this case.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that it's basically bad practice to encode your enumerations into the script. Therefore, create a table with the enumerations present (and their relative keys), then it's a simple case of grouping a left joined query...

```
SELECT 
    cat.enum_name, 
    COUNT(data.id) AS total 
FROM
    category_table cat
    LEFT JOIN
    data_table data
        ON  cat.cate_id = data.cat_id 
 GROUP BY 
    cat.enum_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a fictive dataset of the different categories and do a left join with your original table as shown below.

```
 SELECT A.category, count(*) total FROM
 (SELECT 'one' as Category 
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 'two' as Category) A
 LEFT JOIN items B
 ON A.Category=B.Category
 GROUP BY B.Category;
```

If you would prefer to get a list of all the category dynamically, then save them in another table (say `All_category_table`) then do a join as shown below:

```
 SELECT A.category, count(*) total FROM
 (SELECT Category FROM All_category_table) A
 LEFT JOIN items B
 ON A.Category=B.Category
 GROUP BY B.Category;
```

Comment: Can I construct this fictive dataset dynamically based on the possible enum values?

Comment: This query won't count zero categories. @voutasaurus Did you have solved it?

Comment: Nope sorry, still using `select category, count(*) as total from items group by category;`. Let me know if you figure it out though!

Answer (score 0):

using in-select subquery

```
select  cat.categoryname
   (
      select count(*)  -- count total
      from items as i
      where i.category = cat.category  -- connect

   ) as totalcount
from cat
order by cat.categoryname
```

Answer (score 0):

### This answer is applicable for when you do not have another table holding the possible category values.

Let's say you have a table called `real_table` with a *not null* & *value constrained* column `category`. In this column you know you can theoretically encounter 5 different values: `'CATEGORY_0', 'CATEGORY_1', 'CATEGORY_2', 'CATEGORY_3', 'CATEGORY_4'`:

```
CREATE TABLE real_table
(
    id       VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
        PRIMARY KEY,
    category VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT category_in CHECK (
                category in ('CATEGORY_0',
                             'CATEGORY_1',
                             'CATEGORY_2',
                             'CATEGORY_3',
                             'CATEGORY_4')
            )
);
```

But your actual data set in the table does not include any row with value `'CATEGORY_0'`. So when you run a query such as:

```
SELECT real_table.category AS category, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM real_table
GROUP BY real_table.category;
```

you will see, that you get result like this:

| category | cnt |
| --- | --- |
| CATEGORY_1 | 150 |
| CATEGORY_2 | 20 |
| CATEGORY_3 | 12 |
| CATEGORY_4 | 1 |

*Hmm, the `'CATEGORY_0'` is omitted. Not good.*

Since your categories are not backed by another table, then you must create an artificial dataset of the possible categories that looks as below:

```
SELECT 'CATEGORY_0' AS category_entry
UNION ALL
SELECT 'CATEGORY_1' AS category_entry
UNION ALL
SELECT 'CATEGORY_2' AS category_entry
UNION ALL
SELECT 'CATEGORY_3' AS category_entry
UNION ALL
SELECT 'CATEGORY_4' AS category_entry;
```

You can use this in your original query as a table to do a right join on:

```
SELECT all_categories.category_entry AS category,
       COUNT(real_table.id)          AS cnt -- important to count some non-null value, such as PK of the real_table
FROM real_table
         RIGHT JOIN
     (SELECT 'CATEGORY_0' AS category_entry -- not present in any row in table 'all_categories'
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 'CATEGORY_1' AS category_entry
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 'CATEGORY_2' AS category_entry
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 'CATEGORY_3' AS category_entry
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 'CATEGORY_4' AS category_entry) all_categories
     ON real_table.category = all_categories.category_entry
GROUP BY all_categories.category_entry;
```

Now when you run the query, you should get the desired output:

| category | cnt |
| --- | --- |
| **CATEGORY_0** | **0** |
| CATEGORY_1 | 150 |
| CATEGORY_2 | 20 |
| CATEGORY_3 | 12 |
| CATEGORY_4 | 1 |

*The `'CATEGORY_0'` is now included with zero cnt. Nice.*

Now let's say that the `category` column is **not** *not null* constrained and can **also possibly include** some other unexpected `category` values (e.g. `'CATEGORY_66'`):

```
CREATE TABLE real_table
(
    id       VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
        PRIMARY KEY,
    category VARCHAR(255) -- nullable and no constraint for valid values
);
```

We would like to include these *null* and *unexpected* `category` counts in the result set as well.
Then we must prepare the artificial dataset of the possible categories differently:

```
SELECT DISTINCT all_categories.category_entry
FROM (SELECT 'CATEGORY_0' AS category_entry -- not present in any row in table 'all_categories'
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 'CATEGORY_1' AS category_entry
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 'CATEGORY_2' AS category_entry
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 'CATEGORY_3' AS category_entry
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 'CATEGORY_4' AS category_entry
      UNION ALL
      SELECT DISTINCT category
      FROM real_table AS category_entry) all_categories;
```

and use it as before:

```
SELECT distinct_categories.category_entry AS category,
       COUNT(real_table.id)               AS cnt -- important to count some non-null value, such as PK of the real_table
FROM real_table
         RIGHT JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT all_categories.category_entry
      FROM (SELECT 'CATEGORY_0' AS category_entry -- not present in any row in table 'all_categories'
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 'CATEGORY_1' AS category_entry
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 'CATEGORY_2' AS category_entry
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 'CATEGORY_3' AS category_entry
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 'CATEGORY_4' AS category_entry
            UNION ALL
            SELECT DISTINCT category
            FROM real_table AS category_entry) all_categories) distinct_categories
     ON real_table.category = distinct_categories.category_entry
GROUP BY distinct_categories.category_entry;
```

Now when you run the query, the output should also include counts for additional categories and *null* categories

| category | cnt |
| --- | --- |
| CATEGORY_0 | 0 |
| CATEGORY_1 | 150 |
| CATEGORY_2 | 20 |
| CATEGORY_3 | 12 |
| CATEGORY_4 | 1 |
| **CATEGORY_66** | **13** |
|  | **10** |

*Both *unexpected* `'CATEGORY_66'` (with 13 entries) as well as *null* category (with 10 entries) are now included in the result set*

I cannot vouch for the performance of the provided queries - somebody more experienced might weigh in on that?