# Get most frequent top 10 items found in a HTML column using Count

Tags: mysql

I have a bit of a messy query to try figure out.

I have a column called "meta_value" and in that I have some HTML data such as:

```
<tr class="child-row123"><td class="monsters">Monster</td><td class="monsters"><a data-name="Zure, Knight of Dark World">Zure, Knight of Dark World</a> x1</br><a data-name="Dark Necrofear">Dark Necrofear</a> x1</br><a data-name="Grapha, Dragon Lord of Dark World">Grapha, Dragon Lord of Dark World</a> x3</br><a data-name="Reign-Beaux, Overlord of Dark World">Reign-Beaux, Overlord of Dark World</a> x1</br><a data-name="Goldd, Wu-Lord of Dark World">Goldd, Wu-Lord of Dark World</a> x1</br><a data-name="Sillva, Warlord of Dark World">Sillva, Warlord of Dark World</a> x3</br><a data-name="Beiige, Vanguard of Dark World">Beiige, Vanguard of Dark World</a> x2</br><a data-name="Brron, Mad King of Dark World">Brron, Mad King of Dark World</a> x3</br><a data-name="Trance Archfiend">Trance Archfiend</a> x3</br><a data-name="Kahkki, Guerilla of Dark World">Kahkki, Guerilla of Dark World</a> x3</br><a data-name="Scarr, Scout of Dark World">Scarr, Scout of Dark World</a> x2</br></td></tr><tr class="child-row123"><td class="spells">Spells</td><td class="spells"><a data-name="Dark Core">Dark Core</a> x1</br><a data-name="Dark World Dealings">Dark World Dealings</a> x2</br><a data-name="Dark World Lightning">Dark World Lightning</a> x3</br><a data-name="The Gates of Dark World">The Gates of Dark World</a> x3</br><a data-name="Gateway to Dark World">Gateway to Dark World</a> x2</br></td></tr><tr class="child-row123"><td class="traps">Traps</td><td class="traps"><a data-name="Dark Scheme">Dark Scheme</a> x1</br><a data-name="The Forces of Darkness">The Forces of Darkness</a> x1</br><a data-name="Dark Smog">Dark Smog</a> x1</br><a data-name="Dark World Brainwashing">Dark World Brainwashing</a> x3</br><a data-name="Depth Amulet">Depth Amulet</a> x1</br></td></tr><tr class="child-row123"><td class="extra">Extra</td><td class="extra"><a data-name="Number 23: Lancelot, Dark Knight of the Underworld">Number 23: Lancelot, Dark Knight of the Underworld</a> x1</br></td></tr><tr class="child-row123"><td class="id">Id</td><td class="id"></td></tr>
```

I have over 6000 of these rows and I'm trying to find the top 10 most frequent values found in them without killing the server.

As an example, I can find how many times a card called "LANphorhynchus" appears by doing the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(meta_value))
FROM wph3_postmeta
WHERE meta_value LIKE "%>LANphorhynchus</a>%"
AND meta_key = "deck_list"
```

Which is great! But I want to try figure it out for a top 10 where I don't specifically know which names are in the top 10.

Is this something that should even be performed within MySQL?

**Clarification:**

As stated, the meta_value column contains complete HTML markup. Each card name is inserted here as:

```
<a data-name="LANphorhynchus">LANphorhynchus</a>
```

and each row has multiple card names within this meta_value column (see top for full example of data in a row). So I am searching for them in MySQL with `"%>LANphorhynchus</a>%"` if I want a specific card (I need to search in between tags).

However. I want to try attempt to get the Top 10 cards found in this column from all rows where I don't know the card name.
So I'm possibly thinking some **regex** might be needed to search in between the tags for each row and find which card appears most often?

Extract of a database row: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1625ha8zGlCGvVnRa8N3cwpqVqg1JxF5mT8i04CENRWc/edit?usp=sharing

**ANSWER:**
Thanks to Midwinter86, I was able to look at this from a new perspective.

What I have done is the following.

> Run a query on top 100 most viewed cards in my database and insert the names into an array.
>
> Within a loop, check each of those names specifically against the `meta_values` table to see how often they appear (using my LANphorhynchus example above).
>
> Extract all data to a new table top_10_cards.
>
> Cache data for 1 week and then re-run.

**Output**:

```
+-----------------------------+---------+
|            name             |  count  |
+-----------------------------+---------+
| Monster Reborn              |    2842 |
| Ash Blossom & Joyous Spring |    2587 |
| Knightmare Phoenix          |    2231 |
| Borreload Dragon            |    1975 |
+-----------------------------+---------+
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant rows!

Comment: Roughly, what will be the max count of card names in a particular row (meta_value) ? Also, I can see a card as `"Jerry Beans Man"`; should it be treated as a single card, or three cards: `Jerry`, `Beans` and `Man` ?

Comment: Roughly there are usually 40 - 60 cards inserted in a particular row, more so 40. Jerry Beans Man is 1 single card. As shown in the clarification, the markup for a single card is <a data-name="LANphorhynchus">LANphorhynchus</a>

Comment: I would still be very interested in a pure MySQL approach if you have it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following is purely MySQL-only solution; you can run this query once (or twice) a day in off-peak hours, to update the count in a cache/summary table. Moreover, number of rows are roughly around 6000 (only), so (depending on your server configuration), it *should* not cause performance issues.

Now, since the number of cards in a particular row is variable (can range from 40-60), we can use a Sequence table. You can define a permanent table in your database storing integers ranging from 1 to 100 (you *may* find this table helpful in many other cases as well):

```
CREATE TABLE seq (n tinyint(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(n));
INSERT INTO seq (n) VALUES (1), (2), ...... , (99), (100);
```

Now, we will do a `JOIN` between `wph3_postmeta` and `seq` table, based on the count of occurrence of substring `'data-name=""'` inside the specific `meta_value`. [We can get the count of occurrence of the substring](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5427534/2469308) (which also means, count of cards in a particular row) using:

```
(
  CHAR_LENGTH(wp.meta_value) 
  - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(wp.meta_value, 'data-name=""', ''))
) / CHAR_LENGTH('data-name=""')
```

Now, we can use the [`Substring_Index()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) function to extract the card values out. Using the different numbers in different row, we can basically extract out the first card, second card, and so on...

Once we have extracted all the words out, in separate rows; we can then use the complete result-set as a [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html), and perform the aggregation queries to get the required results:

**Query ([View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7ges9EJjuy2Kp6JLciuxct/3))**

```
SELECT dt.name,
       Count(DISTINCT dt.meta_id) AS unique_metaid_count
FROM   (SELECT wp.meta_id,
               Substring_index(Substring_index(wp.meta_value, 'data-name=""',
                               -seq.n),
               '"">', 1
               ) AS name
        FROM   wph3_postmeta AS wp
               JOIN seq
                 ON ( Char_length(wp.meta_value) - Char_length(
                                                   REPLACE(wp.meta_value,
                                                   'data-name=""'
                                                        ,
                                                        '')) ) /
                         Char_length('data-name=""') >= n
        WHERE  wp.meta_key = 'deck_list') AS dt
GROUP  BY dt.name
ORDER  BY unique_metaid_count DESC  
/* To get top 10 counts only, add LIMIT 10 */
```

**Result**

```
| name                                          | unique_metaid_count |
| --------------------------------------------- | ------------------- |
| Call of the Haunted                           | 2                   |
| Inferno Reckless Summon                       | 2                   |
| Mystic Box                                    | 2                   |
| Mystical Space Typhoon                        | 2                   |
| Number 39: Utopia                             | 2                   |
| #created by ygopro2                           | 1                   |
| 98095162                                      | 1                   |
| Abyss Dweller                                 | 1                   |
| Advanced Ritual Art                           | 1                   |
| Armed Dragon LV3                              | 1                   |
| Armed Dragon LV5                              | 1                   |
| Axe of Despair                                | 1                   |
| B.E.S. Covered Core                           | 1                   |
.....

| The Dragon Dwelling in the Cave               | 1                   |
| The Flute of Summoning Dragon                 | 1                   |
| The Forces of Darkness                        | 1                   |
| Threatening Roar                              | 1                   |
| Time Machine                                  | 1                   |
| Torike                                        | 1                   |
| Tornado Dragon                                | 1                   |
| Torrential Tribute                            | 1                   |
| Tragoedia                                     | 1                   |
| Trap Hole                                     | 1                   |
| Treeborn Frog                                 | 1                   |
| Trishula, Dragon of the Ice Barrier           | 1                   |
| Twin Twisters                                 | 1                   |
| Vanity's Ruler                                | 1                   |
| Wind-Up Snail                                 | 1                   |
| Wind-Up Soldier                               | 1                   |
| Wulf, Lightsworn Beast                        | 1                   |
| Zure, Knight of Dark World                    | 1                   |
```

**Note:** If you want Top 10 only (by count), you can simply add `LIMIT 10` at the end of the query.

Comment: Wow this is fantastic and well detailed for a pure SQL code method. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how frequently you need to perform this and the size of the dataset, I would probably extract this data out in to a new table. I would create a table with pk, card_name (unique), count and then write a command in the application to iterate over the existing data to parse the out the names from the tag bodies or the data-name attribute in the html and create the row or update the count in the row, and then make the change in the application to make sure that column gets updated whenever meta_value changes.

Doing it this way and just sorting based on the count field will be more performant when for this specific lookup, but it will also make this query still be valid should the structure of your html ever change. It also allows for you at add other properties to these items

Comment: Thank you! This helped me look at it from a new point of view. I've updated my OP to describe the answer I have implemented thanks to this new insight.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need a simple LIMIT and ORDER BY Clause -

```
SELECT meta_value, COUNT(DISTINCT meta_value) VALUE_COUNT
FROM wph3_postmeta
WHERE meta_key = "deck_list"
AND meta_value REGEXP '>[[:alnum:]]+(</a>)$'
GROUP BY meta_value
ORDER BY VALUE_COUNT DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer! Unfortunately not what  am looking for. The problem with this, is that it will output full HTML values within meta_value. As you can see in my example above, I have to search within the HTML of meta_value to extract the card names. Example: "%>LANphorhynchus</a>%"

Comment: @GenesisBits, Please see if updated answer works for you.

Comment: I've added some clarification to the bottom of the OP for what I am looking for exactly. Thanks!

Comment: @GenesisBits, Please see if updated answer having regular expressions helps you here.

Comment: Unfortunately no, it just returns 0 rows.

Comment: Please post the sample structure and data of that table. I will test it at my end and will update my answer.

Comment: Thanks! I've added a google sheets link at the bottom of a database row extract.