# How to get unique / distinct elements inside JSON array in MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, json, mysql-5.7

I have mysql 5.7 with a denormalized table that has some JSON columns. I need to extract unique / distinct values per row for an array column.

For e.g: `["a", "b", "b", "a", "c"]` expected output should be `["a", "b", "c"];`

`SET @json = '["a", "b", "b", "a", "c"]';`
I need to get unique values in this list.

`["a", "b", "c"];`

Comment: Seems more like something you should do at the app level vs directly from the database

Comment: Or if you want to use SQL operations like `DISTINCT` on the values, then store each value in a separate row. In other words, use JSON only to store and fetch the whole JSON document verbatim. Do not expect to use SQL operations to search, sort, or aggregate elements of JSON documents as if they were discrete relational data.

Comment: You might look into the Multi Value Indexes found in MySQL 8.0.17 to index all the array entries and look for distinct document identifiers.

Answer (score 3):

There is no direct method to get distinct values out of a JSON array in MySQL. One method could be to [utilize a Sequence/Number Generator table concept](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58032575/2469308). This sequence table could be used as a Derived Table (subquery), or you can create a permanent table storing numbers in your database.

We will then use this sequence table to [`JSON_EXTRACT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract) values out from array at first key, second key, third key and so on. Once we have extracted out the values in separate row, we can simply use `DISTINCT` to get unique values out of them. Afterwards, we can use [`JSON_ARRAYAGG()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg) function to re-aggregate these unique values back as a JSON array.

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
SET @json = '["a", "b", "b", "a", "c"]';
```

**Query**

```
SELECT Json_arrayagg(dt.val) AS unq_json_array
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT Json_extract(@json, Concat('$[', seq.n, ']')) AS val
        FROM   (SELECT 0 AS n UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL 
                SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL
                SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL
                SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS seq) AS dt
WHERE  dt.val IS NOT NULL;
```

**Result**

```
| unq_json_array  |
| --------------- |
| ["a", "b", "c"] |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mUyKpViMcGuVdMBNDrHWQr/0)

Answer (score 3):

The following may help those using **MySQL 8**

You could use a combination of `JSON_TABLE`, `JSON_OBJECTAGG`, and `JSON_KEYS` to do it without too much trouble. It's too bad we couldn't do something like `JSON_ARRAYAGG(DISTINCT item)`.

For example:

```
SET @json = '["a", "b", "b", "a", "c"]';

SELECT JSON_KEYS(JSON_OBJECTAGG(item, ""))
FROM JSON_TABLE(@json, '$[*]'
    COLUMNS(
        item TEXT PATH '$'
    )
) as items;
```

I also made a DBFiddle to show my work: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6hgSEXPJWcm2CH8K16z6gQ/0

> JSON_TABLE https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html
>
> JSON Search Functions: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html

Comment: There is an issue with this, in that it is not case insensitive, so it will return two results if the JSON is {"One","one"].

Comment: @JustinLevene the OP has no mention of a case-insensitive approach. This should be easy to add by wrapping the JSON with MySQL's lower function. `lower(@json)`

Answer (score 0):

Until we have `JSON_ARRAYAGG(DISTINCT item)`, the only way to do it using a distinct is, meaning it will act exactly the same:

**DATA**

```
set @json = '["a","b","c","A","B","d"]';
```

**SQL**

```
SELECT json_arrayagg(`d`)
from 
(
     select distinct `d`
     from json_table(@json, '$[*]' COLUMNS(`d` TEXT PATH '$')) `i`
)`g`;
```

**RESULT**

```
["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

The above will treat "A" the same as "a" if your character set collation is case insensitive, like utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci (the ci means it is case insensitive on comparisons).